# EF Core Power Tools Reverse engineer create different attributes on model on different SQL servers

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-power-tools

I'm using EF Core Power Tools to generate my model by choosing EF Core Power Tools -> Reverse Enegineer within Visual Studio .Net.

I'm still using EF Core 2.x, so I remove the checkmark from the first dialog where you can choose to use EF Core 3.x.

In the last options dialog I select:

- Use DataAnnotation attributes to configure the model.
- Customize code using Handlebars templates (C#).

I'm using SQL Server for my databases.

My problem is that the model generated is different when I run the tools on my local database compared to a version of the database on another server.

The difference is in the generated POCO class.
On my local database, the following class is generated:

```
public partial class ExampleTable
{
    [Key]
    public byte Id { get; set; }
    public string Tekst { get; set; }
}
```

When I run the tool against another database the code looks like this:

```
[Table("ExampleTable", Schema = "dbo")]
public partial class ExampleTable
{
    [Key]
    public byte Id { get; set; }
    public string Tekst { get; set; }
}
```

Why is the tool generating the model with attributes on dbo tables on one databse and without attributes on another database?

Comment: I guess `another database` might have `default schema` other than `dbo` for user which you have used in `connectionstring`.

Comment: You are right that was the problem, there were no default default scheme for the user on the other database. Then the good question is why that was the case :-)
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Karan said, this is because the user used for scaffolding does not have dbo as default schema.

see https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/master/src/EFCore.Design/Scaffolding/Internal/CSharpEntityTypeGenerator.cs#L174

Comment: You are right that was the problem, there were no default default scheme for the user on the other database. Then the good question is why that was the case :-)
Thanks for your help.